# Getting table data from web page using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage that displays some products, and I need to go to each of these products and obtain the table data under the tab called technical details, and get this data into one big table in excel. I wrote the following code, but I seem to get a blank excel file. Where is it going wrong?

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def cpap_spider(url):
    global row_i
    
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'name name2_padd'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        title = link.string
        worksheet.write(row_i, 0, title)
        each_item(href)
        print(href)
        

def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'width_table'})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.select('td')
      for ele in range(0, len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          if temp[-1] == ':':
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names = []
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('st.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Title')
    
cpap_spider('https://www.respshop.com/cpap-machines/manual/')

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The product info is loaded via Ajax from another URL.

This script will load all technical parameters along name/url of the product:

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.respshop.com/cpap-masks/nasal/'
product_info_url = 'https://www.respshop.com/product_info.php'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for item in soup.select('td.name a'):
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(item['href'], headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
    sku = s.select_one('[itemprop="mpn"]').text
    print(item.text, sku)
    products_id = re.search(r'p-(\d+)\.html', item['href'])[1]

    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(product_info_url, data={'products_id': products_id, 'tab': 3}, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

    row = {'Name': item.text, 'SKU': sku, 'URL': item['href']}
    for k, v in zip(s.select('#cont_3 td.main:nth-child(1)'),
                    s.select('#cont_3 td.main:nth-child(2)')):
        row[k.get_text(strip=True)] = v.get_text(strip=True)
    all_data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
ComfortGel Blue Nasal CPAP Mask - Philips Respironics  1070038, 1070037, 1070039, 1070040, 1070050, 1070051, 1070052, 1070049
Wisp Nasal Mask - Philips Respironics  1094051, 1094050, 1109298
Dreamwear Nasal Mask - Philips Respironics 1116700, 1116680, 1116681, 1116682, 1116683, 1116685, 1116686, 1116687, 1116688, 1116690, 1116691, 1116692, 1116693
Airfit N20 Nasal CPAP Mask by ResMed w/ 5 Free Cushions 63536, 63538, 63539
Airfit N30i - ResMed Nasal Mask  63800, 63801
New Respironics DreamWear Nasal Mask With Headgear Arm FitPack 1142376
ResMed AirFit N30 CPAP Nasal Cradle Mask 64222, 64223, 64224

...etc.
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Would I have to change headers corresponding to my system?

Comment: @huy I added the `import re`. You need to load the product data from `https://www.respshop.com/product_info.php` with correct parameters.

Comment: ok got it! i also wanted a column that could get the tiny numbers printed on left as model: xxxx,.. for each product. I cant seem to locate its path for the code you wrote. Any suggestions?

Comment: this gets only maximum of 2 SKU numbers , even when there are multiple present for a product

Comment: https://www.respshop.com/cpap-masks/nasal/respironics-comfortgel-blue-nasal-cpap-mask-p-162.html

Comment: Hi. Could you explain how you are writing the code, eg. how you are getting things inside soup.select(). I have been trying to extend this code for https://www.1800wheelchair.com/product/22-bariatric-aluminum-transport-chair/, but I am not able to understand how I can do that